# Twitter Bootstrap css - keep layout fixed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to keep my Twitter Bootstrap layout from jumbling around when the browser size changes. I essentially want to keep a minimum width.

I've followed the directions on the bootstrap page to not have the fluid container or fluid rows, and I also tried adding a minimum width tag in the body, but for some reason have failed to get it to work correctly - I'm thinking there's got to be an easy solution here that I'm missing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

This is Bootstrap's [responsive feature](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive).
If you don't want it, don't reference responsive.less.

Comment: I think they're called bootstrap-responsive.css and bootstrap-responsive.min.css.

Comment: Removing the responsive.less file was a much easier fix than I anticipated. Thanks for this, @SLaks!

Answer (score 0):

As SLaks said, the layout resizing is in Bootstrap's responsive code. If you're compiling the LESS files, don't include responsive.less (which in turn includes the other responsive less files in v2.0.3). Incidentally, responsive.less is *not* included by default.

If you're adding the supplied .css files (i.e., not compiling from LESS), just include bootstrap.css/bootstrap.min.css and not bootstrap-responsive.css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css on your page and it should work.